# Reattach to Emacs session

Tags: emacs

I was trying to save in Emacs and pushed something wrong and Emacs closed. Judging by

```
ps aux | grep emacs
```

the `emacs` process is still running with the file I need to save running. (Opening the file in new `emacs` process complains that the file is used by another `emacs` process).

How can I reattach to the running Emacs session or at least make it save its work before I kill it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found out I was pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>.

Solution was to execute:

```
fg %emacs
```

Comment: I only have to hit C-z to suspend emacs, and then `fg` to resume it. It **should** be possible to disable this with `stty susp ''` (as it's very easy to mistype, that'd be great) but it is not working for me (i.e., still possible to suspend).

Comment: @EmanuelBerg `stty susp` only applies when the terminal is in [cooked](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/whats-the-difference-between-a-raw-and-a-cooked-device-driver) mode. Emacs put the terminal in raw mode and handles combinations like `Ctrl+Z` internally.

Comment: To disable this, in `.emacs`, put: `(put 'suspend-frame 'disabled t)` - but, if you accidentally mistype, you'll still get an annoying popup message saying it is disabled, so use `C-h f suspend-frame RET` to find out what keys will do it, then (in my case) `(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") nil)` and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-z") nil)`.