# Gawk: backspace preceding a newline doesn't work

Tags: awk, escape-characters, gawk

I'm using gawk (4.1.3) and it seems I have struck upon a trivial problem.
The backspace character doesn't seem to work if it is immediately followed by a newline.

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) printf("%d,",i); printf("\b\n")}'
```

gives me `1,2,3,` (the last comma isn't gone)

This doesn't get resolved even if I put the `\n` in a new `printf` function.

However, if I insert any character between `\b` and `\n` (for instance, a space), it works.

If I remove `\n` it again works.

What is this issue?

Comment: I think this is more to do with the way the terminal interprets backspace - see for example the somewhat related [Behaviour of the backspace on terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414164/65304)

Answer (score 2):

`\b` only moves the cursor, it does not overwrite the text.

To write out a comma separated list in `awk`, one option is to create a proper record and print it:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    $0 = ""

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
      $i = i

    print
}
```

The output would be `1,2,3`.

And for the one-liner crowd:

```
awk -vOFS=',' 'BEGIN { for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) $i = i; print }'
```

Setting `$0` to an empty string is not *really* necessary here since we only have a `BEGIN` block and no input data, so I left it out from the one-line variation.