# Bash bind command does not work correctly for interactive commands

Tags: bash, command, stdin

When I try bind some commands with `bind -x` bash utility, I can't see my stdin input on terminal.

Example:

`root> # bind -x '"\C-p": su dargod'`

When I type ctrl+P - I login to user dargod, but all what I types not shows.
Same situation with bind ssh command for connect.

How I can normally interract with shell?

Info:

Bash 3.1.17 (CentOS 5)
Bash 4.2.46 (CentOS 7)
Bash 4.1.2 (CentOS 6)
Bash 5.0.7 (Arch Linux)
Bash 4.2.45 (Gentoo)

Comment: What is the info?  Are those all the machines you have tried on or does your machine shift between operating systems and bash versions?

Comment: Yes, In the info indicated on which systems I tried and with which versions bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands bound to a key are meant to be used as part of line editing. They run with the terminal in raw mode without echo, with bash expecting to handle each key press¹. Most commands expect to run with the terminal in [cooked mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/what-s-the-difference-between-a-raw-and-a-cooked-device-driver), where the terminal reads one line at a time and echoes the input.

To run a command that takes over the terminal interaction, temporarily set the terminal to cooked mode.

```
bind -x '"\C-p": _bash_stty_save=$(stty -g); stty sane; su dargod; stty "$_bash_stty_save"'
```

Note that this may still not work perfectly, because you're doing something that bash doesn't expect. Bindings are not the right tool to run a command. To define a shortcut for a command, use an [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases).

---

<sup>¹ strictly speaking, it's not a complete raw mode as `^C`, `^Z`,`^\` (`isig`) and `^Q` / `^S` (`ixon`) are not disabled in bash' line editor (even though `^S` conflicts with its emacs mode incremental search).</sup>