# canonical/non-canonical vs raw/cooked?

Tags: terminal, drivers, tty, devices

In the context of terminals, what is the difference between the two opposites canonical/non-canonical and cooked/raw?

[This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/what-s-the-difference-between-a-raw-and-a-cooked-device-driver) says that they are synonym. But that's weird because one of the "local settings" in `stty` is `icanon`, while `cooked` or `raw` are "combination settings", in which icanon is one of the settings in the combinations.

Answer (score -1):

> `cooked` or `raw` are "combination settings"

Yes, that's true, as described in `stty`'s manual page.

Maybe some people use sloppy wording, e.g. they say `canonical` or `non-canonical` whereas actually they mean a combination of multiple flags (out of which arguably `[non]canonical` is the most important), i.e. they actually mean `cooked` vs. `raw`. I think that in some contexts such sloppiness is fully acceptable and doesn't cause misunderstanding.

Not so much in the first paragraph of the linked answer, where the goal is to explain the meaning of these words, and the poster explicitly says that they are equivalent. That part of that answer is just wrong.